# How do I deploy the files from my app bucket in GCS from cloud shell in App engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create my first php app using GCS.

I have placed all my php app files in the bucket (including my .yaml file) created by the app engine, but I am struggling to access the files to deploy the app using the cloud shell in app engine?

If I has them stored in git I would have used the clone commands but would assume that this would have placed the files in the same bucket that I have manually uploaded the files to through the bucket browser?!

I either cant find the correct file path as the buckets do not appear to be part of my /home/username directory or I am missing a key link like an API to the cloud storage service (GSUtil?).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

JH

Comment: robsiemb's answer is correct. I recommend following a Google example to learn the basics of deploying an App Engine Standard application. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be manually placing any files into the (app's staging) GCS bucket yourself to deploy an app to app engine.

Instead, place the files (including your `app.yaml`) in a working directory on your machine (or cloud shell), then use the `gcloud app deploy` [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) to deploy them.  You can see an example of how to deploy a PHP app [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/quickstart).  The `gcloud app deploy` command is going to look for the source files on the local filesystem.

Note that using git isn't a requirement (though using some form of source control is always a good development practice), it is just the way the files are copied onto the local machine in this example.

(Likewise -- GCS buckets won't show up in the cloud shell filesystem -- GCS is a blob storage service not a normal filesystem, so you would need to use a tool like [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) or the [GCS API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/) to access it).